# Create Index equivalent from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a current index that I have pulled from Oracle and I am trying to add to SQL Server. As far as I can tell, I will have to remove the double quotes and use `WITH(...` However, I cannot find the Maxtrans and other keywords equivalent in SQL Server, especially the `M_ROW$$`, which I was thinking it would be the `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ""MYDB"".""I_SNAP$MYTABLE"" ON 
""MYDB"".""MYTABLE"" (""M_ROW$$"")          
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 NOLOGGING COMPUTE STATISTICS             
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645           
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)            
TABLESPACE ""IL_MIS_INDX""
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: `M_ROW$$` is the name of a column on the table `I_SNAP$MYTABLE`. As far as I can see it has no relation to `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Those double-doublequotes aren't an Oracle thing. If you create a table named `XYZ` then tools tend to generate DDL as `CREATE TABLE "SOMEUSER"."XYZ"` to be on the safe side, with all the [storage defaults](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses007.htm#SQLRF30011) like `PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255`.  Yes you can remove all double quotes unless they are explicitly preserving some non-standard name. `MAXTRANS` is deprecated, and the other storage parameters are ignored anyway for automated segment space management, which has been the default for a long time.

Comment: By the way, it looks like `I_SNAP$MYTABLE` is a materialized view log, which [appears not to have any equivalent in SQL Server](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d0224850-0807-49ab-bebf-1a34b7127852/materialized-view-logmlog-equivalent-in-sql-server?forum=sqldatabaseengine). It's possible that it's not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't need all the options.  So, just use the default syntax:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX <MYDB.I_SNAP$MYTABLE> ON MYDB.MYTABLE (<M_ROW$$>)
```

Of course, the table name and column name needs to be the actual names in SQL Server.

I am speculating that you don't need the index options in SQL Server.  If you do, you will need to optimize the index for that database, rather than assuming that what works in Oracle will automatically work in SQL Server.

Comment: Gordon, Thank you for your answer. I was trying to keep the same structure in both environments. Of course, if that is not a possibility, I can definitely scale it down. However, if I can keep as close as possible, the better.

Comment: What Gordon wrote preserves all logical structure, all other stuff is just options which are database engine dependant, may affect performace only and are not 1:1 portable